# Приложения и пояснительные члены предложения

Tags: приложение

Я не могу  понять, приложение — это пояснительный член предложения, или это совсем разные части речи. Еще не понимаю, когда имя собственное — это приложение, а когда — пояснение.

Comment: Не путайте части речи с членами предложения. Части речи — это существительное, прилагательное, глагол и т.д. А приложение (как вид определения) и пояснительная конструкция — члены предложения.

Comment: Так как их отличить друг от друга?